# Redirect and at the end of navigation call another method. Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a login screen, a landing screen and a Modal Popup Screen.

One of the scenarios is User successfully Logs In --> Show Landing page --> Show Modal Popup screen.

Login.ts : has the code to Redirect and call another method of a different component.

```
@ViewChild(ModalPopup)
public modalPoupup: ModalPopup| undefined;
getBillingPage(){
   let user = this.userService.getUser();
   this.redirect(this.landingPage.toString());
   this.modalPoupup.openMyModal();
   }
```

ModalPopup.ts: has the methods to show/hide the Modal

```
public openMyModal() { 
   this.myModal.show();
   }
```

The above code successfully redirects but doesn't open the Modal popup.

**If I remove the `redirect()` in the Login.ts and just have openMyModal(), the modal is shown but when the Modal is closed it still shows the Login page instead of Landing page.**

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: impossible to say what is wrong unless I know how do these components look, what is going on in `this.redirect(this.landingPage.toString());` . This question will be voted "close" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code **router.navigate(['Page'])** to redirect the page after the login is complete, you have to import the Router library.

example:

```
login(){
this.userServ.postlogin(this.users)
.subscribe( (res:any) => {
  localStorage.setItem('token',res.token );
  console.log(res)
  this.router.navigate(['private'])
});
```

}